# In R can I save loaded packages with the workspace?

Tags: r, package, workspace

R normally only saves objects in .GlobalEnv:

```
$ R
> library(rjson)
> fromJSON
function (...) ...
> q(save='yes')
$ R
> fromJSON
Error: object 'fromJSON' not found
```

Is there a way to have this information saved as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are now able to save R session information to a file and load it in another session.

First install the "session" package:

```
install.packages('session')
```

Load your libraries and your data, then save the session state to a file:

```
library(session)
library(ggplot2) # plotting

test <- 100

save.session(file='test.Rda')
```

Then you can load the session state in another session:

```
library(session)

restore.session(file='test.Rda')

#ggplot2 (and associated data) should have loaded with the session data
head(diamonds)
ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = carat)) +
  geom_histogram()

print(test)
```

Reference: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/session/versions/1.0.3/topics/save.session

Answer (score 5):

To the best of my knowledge, no. The workspace is for *objects* like data and functions. Starting R with particular packages loaded is what your .Rprofile file is for, and you can have a different one in each directory.

You could, I suppose, save a function in the workspace that loads the packages you want, and then run that function when you first start R.

Answer (score 2):

joran is right, but I want to mention a technique that, while cumbersome, might be helpful.

You can use a checkpointing program such as [DMTCP](http://dmtcp.sourceforge.net/) to save the entire R process and restart it later.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend not saving anything between r sessions and instead recreate it all using code. This is much more likely to lead to reproducible results.

Comment: True, and I always try and get everything into code that can be straight-up run when I'm finished, it's just that it gets slow repeatedly running longer and longer scripts.

Comment: Beware also the order in which you include packages, as objects from one may shadow another.